# Is it possible to modify the requester in an Azure DevOps pipeline?

Tags: git, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

We have an Azure DevOps pipeline to run tests, that is triggered by the completion of another pipeline that builds and publishes artifacts when a pull request completes.

Ideally we would like the second pipeline to show the user that completed the original Pull Request, rather than the last person to modify the testing branch. Any failures of the second pipeline would also raise a Work Item and assign it to the user that completed the original Pull Request.

There is a mechanism for updating the build number, but I cannot find a way to update the RequestedFor information.

Update:

I found we can update the Build number using

`Write-Host "##vso[build.updatebuildnumber]$BuildNumber"`

in PowerShell, but cannot find any way the change the requesting user.

Comment: Pull Requests are an add-on (hence Azure or GitHub specific rather than part of Git). I'm guessing this "requester" field is as well. If that's the case, there's no *Git* thing that will do the trick, and you'll need some add-on to fiddle with the added-on stuff. (Not all that helpful but it can save you from going down blind Git alleys.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the second pipeline to show the user that completed the original Pull Request, please use Build.RequestedFor predefined variable to get the user who completed the original Pull Request. Then, use variable group with PowerShell task to transfer the value to the second pipeline. Here is an example below :

1. [Create a variable group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/variable-groups?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic#create-a-variable-group) and [link the variable group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/variable-groups?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic#use-a-variable-group) to both of the two pipelines.

[image]

[image]

2. Add a PowerShell task to the first Pipeline and run REST API to [update the variable group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/variablegroups/update?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0#update-a-variable-group). Pay attention to the **PAT, variable name, variable group name, organization name, project name, groupID.**

   ```
    - task: PowerShell@2
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: | 
          $connectionToken="<PAT>"
          $base64AuthInfo= [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($connectionToken)"))
          $headers = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
          $headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic $base64AuthInfo")
          $headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json")
          $body = '{"variables": {"<variable name>": {"value": "$(Build.RequestedFor)"} },"type": "Vsts","name": "<variable group name>","description": "Updated variable group"}'
          $response = Invoke-RestMethod 'https://dev.azure.com/<organization name>/<project name>/_apis/distributedtask/variablegroups/<groupID>?api-version=5.0-preview.1' -Method 'PUT' -Headers $headers -Body $body
          $response | ConvertTo-Json
   ```
3. Show the variable value in second pipeline that automatically triggered by first pipeline.

```
resources: 
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: <first pipeline name>
    source: <first pipeline name>
    trigger: true

pool:   
  vmImage: windows-latest

steps:
- script: |
    echo Add other tasks to build, test, and deploy your project.
    echo $(<variable name>)   
  displayName: 'Requested For'
```

Comment: So that would share the variables across the pipelines, but can you then update the second pipeline's Build.RequestedFor value, like the way you can the build number using  Write-Host "##vso[build.updatebuildnumber]$BuildNumber"

Comment: All system variables (whether from the server or agent) - this includes System., Agent., Build., and so on should be readonly. Then its contents cannot be changed using ##vso[task.setVariable]. Please refer to https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-yaml/blob/master/design/readonly-variables.md#solution-make-variables-readonly.